# how to awk from n to n elelment

Tags: linux, awk

```
grep -i 'search' var/log/sample.log | less -S | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37}'
```

I want to print from `31` to the end or from `31` to the `34` element only, and I don't want to list them one by one.

Could you reccomend me a `for` loop I could integrate?

Bonus points if you can suggest solution only with `awk`.

Please dont suggest `cut`, as this is not the point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
awk '{for (i = 31; i <= NF; i++)  printf "%s ",$i;printf "\n"}'
```

This will print all the field from 31 to the end 
If you want to have specific limit use code like (to 34 for example):

```
awk '{for (i = 31; i <= 34; i++)  printf "%s ",$i;printf "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints fields *1-3* and *31-last* in one line:

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++)
        printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
    for (i=31; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
    printf "%s", ORS
}'
```

Notes:

- I don't separate fields with explicit space, I use `OFS`. The default value of `OFS` is a space.
- I don't separate records with explicit newline, I use `ORS`. The default value of `ORS` is a newline.

It's good practice to use such standard `awk` variables. If you ever need non-default values, you won't need to change the code (e.g. `awk -v OFS=- …`).

The above code is quite simple but you may or may not like its "policy" regarding `OFS`s: the first `for` loop will always generate exactly 3 `OFS`s, even if the input line is empty; and there will always be at least one trailing `OFS`.

---

The following variant avoids extra `OFS`s:

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=3 && i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", (i==1)? "" : OFS, $i
    for (i=31; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
    printf "%s", ORS
}'
```

Tricks in use:

- The additional condition `i<=NF` in the first `for` loop makes it not print `OFS`s for fields that don't exist in the input.
- Instead of printing `OFS` after a field and trying to suppress the last (trailing) one, we print `OFS` before a field and suppress it for the first field that gets printed. The point is it's easy to tell which field will be printed as the first in the output (even if `NF` may vary); it's not so easy to tell which field will be printed as the last (if `NF` may vary).

---

On the other hand your example code (`{print $1,$2,$3,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37}`) prints 10 fields and *exactly* 9 `OFS`s between them, even if the input line is empty.  I don't know if this is what you need. There is no trailing `OFS` after the last field printed. To achieve something similar, try this:

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++)
        printf "%s%s", (i==1)? "" : OFS, $i
    for (i=31; i<=NF || i<=37; i++)
        printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
    printf "%s", ORS
}'
```

If there are 37 or less fields in the input then there will be exactly 9 `OFS`s; this will behave like your code. Additional fields (38th and further) will generate more `OFS`s and fields in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The all-awk (except for determining the width of your screen which there's no way to do in awk) equivalent of:

```
grep -i 'search' var/log/sample.log | less -S | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37}'
```

is with any awk:

```
awk -v width="$(tput cols)" '
    { $0 = substr($0,1,width) }
    tolower($0) ~ /search/ {
        for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
        }
        for (i=31; i<=37; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, (i<37 ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' var/log/sample.log
```

or with GNU awk for gensub() (untested since you didn't provide any input/output to test against):

```
awk -v width="$(tput cols)" '
    { $0 = substr($0,1,width) }
    tolower($0) ~ /search/ {
        print gensub(/\s*((\S+\s+){3})(\S+\s+){27}((\S+\s+){6}\S+).*/,"\\1\\4",1)
    }
' var/log/sample.log
```